# SQL How to return all rows of a table and limit the rows of another by id and have them joined

Tags: mysql, sql-server

How do i return all rows from the timeslot table and also limit the rows from consultation table by employeeId

This query returns entries with the employeeId =1,

```
SELECT TimeSlot, conStart, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber
FROM TimeSlots
LEFT JOIN consultation
ON TimeSlots.TimeSlot = consultation.conStart
LEFT JOIN patient
ON consultation.patientId = patient.patientID
WHERE employeeId = 1
```

Which gives me this

```
11:00:00.0000000    11:00:00.0000000    chris   wilson  6666666666
```

I would like to know how to show all the Timeslots but only show entries from
one employeeID

This is how i want it to turn out.

```
09:00:00.0000000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

09:20:00.0000000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

09:40:00.0000000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

10:00:00.0000000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

10:20:00.0000000    10:20   tim     is      1111111111

10:40:00.0000000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

11:00:00.0000000    11:00   chris   wilson  6666666666

11:20:00.0000000    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: What table has employeeid? You should include employeeid in your join condition on that table. e.g. if employeeId is in the `consultation` table, include `and employeeid = 1` on the left join. The where condition you currently have is basically making it a regular join.

Comment: Lol i new it had to be something really simple, i have been agonising over this for the last week.

Comment: I just tried this and it works, thank you so much.

Comment: Only tag the appropriate RDMS

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TimeSlot, conStart, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber
FROM TimeSlots
LEFT JOIN consultation
ON TimeSlots.TimeSlot = consultation.conStart
LEFT JOIN patient
ON consultation.patientId = patient.patientId AND employeeId = 1
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TimeSlot, conStart, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber
FROM TimeSlots
     LEFT JOIN (consultation
                LEFT JOIN patient
                ON consultation.patientId = patient.patientID)
     ON TimeSlots.TimeSlot = consultation.conStart AND TimeSlots.employeeId = 1
```